# How to Acess my HDD after wiping it

Tags: data-recovery

I have wiped HDD intentionally as i already have SSD installed for booting, but now the HDD is accessible for storage requirements, basically when i open my computer i cant read it the HDD drives

Comment: Have you formatted the HDD? Have you mounted the partition(s)? Have you assigned the read/write permissions to yourself? **Please edit your question.**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think it has to do with either BIOS, Partition or Both. Try going onto bios setup (it says it when you boot, E.G. F2) Go into that HDD and make sure it says 'on'. Make sure to have GParted installed first, then open GParted and go into the Broken HDD and click 'Add Partition' It's up to you what file system you want to do. I reccomend Ext4 because Linux uses that. Hope I helped!